# How to destroy a component in angular2 router and load new component when the link is pressed?

Tags: typescript, angular

Hello friends i have an angular2 router with two links where one containing a input box and another with normal text.when i enter data into input box and switch between the router links and if i return to the link containing the input box the text entered in the input field still exists.I want to destroy the component and reinitialize the component when i return to the link. Here is my code Link-http://plnkr.co/edit/K90d2GeRegc4G0HjX0FW?p=preview

```
    import {bootstrap, bind, Component, View} from 'angular2/angular2'
import {RouteConfig, RouteParams, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, APP_BASE_HREF, ROUTER_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/router'

@Component({
  selector: 'sup-cmp'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Welcome World</h2>
    </div>
  `
})
class SupCmp {}

@Component({
  selector: 'home-cmp'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div>
    <input type="text" />
    </div>
  `
})
class HomeCmp {}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cmp'
})
@View({
  template: `
    <div>
      <h1>Hello {{message}}!</h1>
      <a [router-link]="['./HomeCmp']">home</a>
      <a [router-link]="['./HelloCmp', {name: 'brian'}]">hello</a>
      <hr>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: ROUTER_DIRECTIVES
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/', component: HomeCmp, as: 'HomeCmp'}
  {path: '/hello/:name', component: SupCmp, as: 'HelloCmp'}
])
export class App {
  message:string = 'world';
}

bootstrap(App, [
  ROUTER_BINDINGS,
  bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue(location.pathname)
]);

// In alpha-38:
//bootstrap(App, [routerBindings(App)]);
```

1.I have 2 links namely Home and Hello.
2.Enter some data into Input box which is in home link and switch to Hello link and return back to home link.
3.The text which u entered still exists.
4.I want to load new component when i click a link...
I dont know how to destroy a component in angular2 router...please help friends...thanks in advance

Comment: But Eric if you enter some text into input box and switch between link the value exists in that input even after going to other links and coming back...

Answer (score -1):

You could use angulars lifecycle events for setting up the initial data.

check out [onInit](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/OnInit-interface.html).